# Is there a way to analyze a MySQL query and determine whether it's read-only?

Tags: mysql, replication

I have a main database and a replica that is automatically kept in sync with the main one. It would be nice, for each query I make, to perform all data- and database-altering queries on the main database, and all read-only queries on the replica. I'm envisioning some kind of query analyzer, and then based on its output, using the correct database, but maybe there's a different way to do that that I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It s called

> "Read/Write Splitting"

like [proxy sql](https://mydbops.wordpress.com/2018/02/19/proxysql-series-mysql-replication-read-write-split-up/)

or [mysql proxy](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-proxy-en.pdf)

You let all querys run over the proxy and it decides with rules to which server the request goes. It will take some time t get it right.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be fairly complicated to do both completely automatic as well as efficient. Imagine a transaction like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
SELECT ... FROM T1 WHERE ...
UPDATE T2 SET ... = ...
SELECT ... FROM T3 WHERE ...
END TRANSACTION
```

Would you direct statement 1 and 3 to your replica whereas statement 2 would be asked against your master?

If not, you need to analyze at the transaction level. That, in turn, can be really complicated due to branching in the code.

A viable option would be to do read-only reporting against your replica

Comment: Can you elaborate on what read-only reporting looks like?

Comment: What I mean by that is that your reports that are read-only are placed in a particular place in your architecture, you somehow disable modifications in the data source that is available to that module. I.e. you don't determine if a query is read-only or not, you put such queries i a specific context, and make sure they can not update the database